# PHP Date and Time, getting the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th week in a month

Tags: php, mysql, loops, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to build a few graphs for ticketing applications.

What I'm trying to do is query the MySQL database for # of tickets created for the 1st, 2nd, 4rd, and 4th week of the current month.

```
  $month_num_tickets = array();
  for ($x=0;$x<=30;$x=$x+6) {    
    $from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00",strtotime('first day of this month +'.$x.' days', time()));       
    $to = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59",strtotime($from, time()));   
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE date_created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$from') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$to') AND assigned_tech_uid='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
    $month_num_tickets[] = mysql_num_rows($get);    
  }
```

Not sure how to setup the loop...

Comment: So you have `date_created` as a timestamp field?  You should REALLY do youself a favor and use a datetime or timestamp field instead. Also, how do you define a week in this sense? You also should just make a singel query on the DB here rather than query in a loop.

Comment: @MikeBrant I plan on it later

Comment: Do you not want to count the tickets that are created after the 4th week of the month? (i.e. between the 29th and 31st days)

Comment: Yes... you don't want to? Just want to be sure.

Comment: Would they be added to the 4th week, or a 5th week?

Comment: This can be tricky. Should the first week end on the first Saturday (Sunday) of the week or should it end after 7 days? Typically I would think that the first week has ended on a specific day of the week.

Comment: @MikelBitson  Begin on Sunday, end on Saturday

Comment: What about the 5th week?

Comment: If weeks start on Sunday and end on Saturday then months can span six(!) weeks. See March, August and November 2014 for some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a nice tidy count in a single query like this:

```
SELECT
    CEIL(DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created)) / 7) AS week_of_month,
    COUNT(id) AS tickets_per_week
FROM tickets
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created)) = ?
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created)) = ?
GROUP BY `week_of_month`
ORDER BY `week_of_month` ASC
```

Note if you used native datetime or timestamp fileds, you could get rid of all of those `FROM_UNIXTIME` conversions.  This is based on a "week" being the first 7 days of the month, not based on specific days of the week.  If you wanted it based on fixed weeks (in terms of sunday through saturday or such) you could just use `WEEK()` function in the SELECT instead.

That might look like this:

```
SELECT
    WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created), 0) AS week_number,
    COUNT(id) AS tickets_per_week
FROM tickets
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created)) = ?
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created)) = ?
GROUP BY `week_number`
ORDER BY `week_number` ASC
```

Here `week_number` would be a value between 0-53 and would not necessarily have any meaning for display  other than as a means for aggregation.  I am using mode 0 for `WEEK()` functoin as this specifies Sun-Sat week.  You can look at the definitions here and determine what mode suits you the best: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

None of these queries are optimized because you won't be able to use an index on `date_created` . If you do get around to changing that column type to a datetime or timestamp, you would also perhaps want to change you WHERE condition to the slightly less easy to read, but more index friendly version like this:

```
WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 23:59:29'
```

Comment: This is infinitely better than attempting to get the week ranges with PHP and insert them into the query, plus eliminates the use of multiple queries if only totals or averages are needed. Unfortunately I don't understand enough about SQL queries to know how you would go about using the WEEK() function in the select method in order to change the ranges to Sunday-started weeks. Does WEEK() instead of DAYOFMONTH() return a value specific to a sunday starting week? Perhaps people want their weeks to start on Monday? I'll go google.

Comment: @MikelBitson I added an example using `WEEK()`

Comment: Awesome! Gotcha, and thank you for the docs link. Should the date that is returned from FROM_UNIXTIME() still be divided by 7? I believe the WEEK() function will work on the date that is returned by FROM_UNIXTIME() without the division?

Comment: @MikelBitson NO it shouldn't. I didn't remove that when copy/pasting.  It is corrected now.

Comment: Hi Mike. I tried to comment on the conversation now about MySQL subqueries, but the OP unfortunately deleted the question. I thought you'd be interested to know I found that MySQL (at least in 5.5) does support the equality operator with a subquery. I ran this on my database: `SELECT * FROM issue WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM issue WHERE code = 'xss')`. The subquery returns one row. If the clause is changed so it returns more than one row, an error is returned: `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(date_created), MONTH(date_created), COUNT(*) FROM tickets 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$from') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$to') AND
 assigned_tech_uid='$uid'
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date_created), MONTH(date_created)
```